# Nodemon is not working : [nodemon] restarting due to changes

Tags: node.js, nodemon, reactjs

I use [nodemon](/questions/tagged/nodemon) as a dev-dependency in node. Suddenly, in CLI it shows:

> [nodemon] restarting due to changes...

when I am changing the code. Then I have globally installed nodemon but it still isn't working.  It is not working on any project-- not a single project.

Any help? I have attached a screenshot of my CLI:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because starting updates a file that the server is watching, therefore triggering a restart event in an infinite loop.

Nodemon supports the `--watch` and `--ignore` commands. Play around with them to only watch a certain set of files. Example:

```sh
# Only watch the "server" directory
nodemon --watch server server/main.js
# Watch both the "server" and "client" directory
nodemon --watch server --watch client server/main.js
# Watch the "server" directory, but ignore "server/logs"
nodemon --watch server --ignore server/logs server/main.js
```

Comment: so what should i write in package.json such as "start": "nodemon app.js"

Comment: I can't tell. I don't know what `app.js` does. I don't know how your project looks like. [Please read the guide on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)