# How to convert http.get response in CSV to JSON NodeJS

Tags: javascript, httpresponse, csvtojson

http.get request returns csv.gz file.
After unzipping I would like to convert it to JSON and upload to mongoDB
How to implement convertation function on stream?

My code is following:

```
  const download = (url, dest) => {
  const request = https.get(url, function(response) {
    const decompress = zlib.createGunzip();
    const file = fs.createWriteStream('./downloads/'+ dest);
    response.pipe(decompress).on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log(chunk)
    })
    .pipe(file);
  });
  }
```

CSV to JSON will convert using that:

```
  const csvToJson = (csv) => {
    const [firstLine, ...lines] = csv.split('\n');
    return lines.map((line) => firstLine.split(',').reduce(
      (curr, next, index) => ({
        ...curr,
        [next]: line.split(',')[index],
      }),
      {},
    ));
  };
```

Calling code as follows:

```
  linksToDownload.map((item) => {
    if (item.value !== undefined) {
    const URL = item.value;
    const DEST = item.name + ".json"
    download(URL, DEST);
    }
  })
```

Also, why nodemon restarts several times?
[printscreen of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yl1i.png)

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: This might answer why nodemon is restarting several times https://stackoverflow.com/a/61032766/8186898